# Separate array information into each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array of information to place in differents divs.
The construction of my divs is ok but all of the information is loaded into the first div.

How can I place each array item into the respective divs?

See my JavaScript code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var works = {

  facebook : {
    image : 'facebook.png',
    description : 'Description One.',
    website : 'http://www.facebook.com'
  },// End facebook
  google : {
    image : 'google.png',
    description : 'Description Two.',
    website : 'http://www.google.com'
  },// End google
  adobe : {
    image : 'adobe.png',
    description : 'Description Three.',
    website : 'http://www.adobe.com'
  }// End adobe

};// End var works

for ( var i in works ){

// Construct the tree of div
$('<div/>', {
    'id' : 'workId' + i,
    'class' : 'work'
}).appendTo("#workListId");

$('<div/>', {
    'id' : 'workFlipId' + i,
    'class' : 'workFlip'
}).appendTo("#workId" + i);

$('<div/>', {
    'id' : 'workDataId' + i,
    'class' : 'workData'
}).appendTo("#workId" + i);

$('<div/>', {
    'id' : 'workDescriptionId' + i,
    'class' : 'workDescription'
}).appendTo("#workDataId" + i);

$('<div/>', {
    'id' : 'workURLId' + i,
    'class' : 'workURL'
}).appendTo("#workDataId" + i);

// Insert the content in each div
var pathBegin = '<img src="img/works/';
var pathEnd = '"/>';

$("#workFlipId" + i).html(pathBegin + works[i].image + pathEnd);
$("#workDescriptionId" + i).html('<p>' + works[i].description + '</p>');
$("#workURLId" + i).html('<a href="' + works[i].website + '">Read more...</a>');

}//End for

$(".work").bind("click",function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.data('flipped'))
    {
        $this.revertFlip();
        $this.data('flipped',false)
    }// End if

    else
    {
        $this.flip({
            direction:'lr',
            color: '#454545',
            speed: 200,
            //content: $('.workData').html(),

            onBefore: function(){

                $this.html($this.siblings('.workData').html());
            }

        });// End $this.flip

        $this.data('flipped',true);

    }// End else
});//End function

}); // End Function
```

Comment: I would use an object instead, it will probably make your code much DRYer and easier to understand...

Comment: Haven't worked through everything you're doing yet (PS, if you're only using jQuery for document.ready, why use it at all? I wouldn't.) but it looks to me like you're duplicating IDs. You can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comments I would use an object instead, it will make your life much easier here. It's pretty hard to read such spaghetti code and really understand what you're trying to achieve, so this is hardly a solution but a suggestion of a different, IMO, better approach. First, your `works` array could be represented like this:

```
var works = {
    facebook : {
        image : 'facebook.png',
        description : 'The biggest social network in the world.',
        website : 'http://www.facebook.com'
    }
    ...
};
```

Then you'd generate the html like so:

```
for (var work in works) {

    var img = '<img src="img/works' + works[work].image + '"/>',
        description = '<p>' + works[work].description + '</p>',
        website = '<a href="' + works[work].website + '">Link</a>';

    ...

}
```

Also, since you're using jQuery, I would use it fully. Take this for example:

```
var work = document.createElement('div');
work.id = 'workId';
work.className = 'work';
...
document.getElementById("workListId").appendChild(work);
```

All of that can be written in jQuery as:

```
$('div', {
    'id' : 'workdId',
    'class' : 'work'
}).appendTo("#workListId");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a div with the same id for each of your array elements.
Add numbering to the id's and it should work.
Here is a modified version of your code in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u5GcE/4/

Answer (score 0):

How about this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mSGg/))?

```
var $works = new Array();
$works[0] = new Array('facebook.png', 'The biggest social network in the world.', 'http://www.facebook.com/');
$works[1] = new Array('adobe.png', 'The leading software developer targeted at web designers and developers.', 'http://www.adobe.com/');
$works[2] = new Array('microsoft.png', 'One of the top software companies of the world.', 'http://www.microsoft.com/');
$works[3] = new Array('sony.png', 'A global multibillion electronics and entertainment company ', 'http://www.sony.com/');
$works[4] = new Array('dell.png', 'One of the biggest computer developers and assemblers.', 'http://www.dell.com/');
$works[5] = new Array('ebay.png', 'The biggest online auction and shopping websites.', 'http://www.ebay.com/');
$works[6] = new Array('digg.png', 'One of the most popular web 2.0 social networks.', 'http://www.digg.com/');
$works[7] = new Array('google.png', 'The company that redefined web search.', 'http://www.google.com/');

var $more = "Read more";

//Random works
var shuffle = false;

$works.sort(function() {
    if (shuffle == true) {
        return 0.7 - Math.random();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
//End random works

function loadWorks()
{
    for (var $loop = 0; $loop < $works.length; $loop++) {
        var $work = $("<div>");
        $work.attr("id", "work"+$loop).attr("class", "work");
        var $workFlip = $("<div>");
        $workFlip.attr("id", "workFlip"+$loop).attr("class", "workFlip");
        $workFlip.html('<img src="img/works/'+$works[$loop][0]+'" >');
        var $workData = $("<div>");
        $workData.attr("id", "workData"+$loop).attr("class", "workData");
        var $workDescription = $("<div>");
        $workDescription.attr("id", "workDescription"+$loop).attr("class", "workDescription");
        $workDescription.html($works[$loop][1]);
        var $workURL = $("<div>");
        $workURL.attr("id", "workURL"+$loop).attr("class", "workURL");
        $workURL.html('<a href="'+$works[$loop][2]+'">'+$more+'</a>');
        $workData.append($workDescription).append($workURL);
        $work.append($workFlip).append($workData);
        $("body").append($work);        
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    loadWorks();
});
​
```

Comment: I agree with @elclanrs, I think it would be easier and more dynamic if you used an object instead as it will be easier to read and change going forward.